# Wrong background for CAB in landscape mode with appcompat-v7 22.2

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I'm using android support v7 appcompat library (version 22.2). I have set a theme to my toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

And set theme for app:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_orange_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_orange_800</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_orange_500</item>
</style>
```

That's what I saw in version 21 in portrait mode and same in landscape mode 
[image: Version 21]

But in version 22.2 I see wrong background in in landscape mode (but right in portrait mode) 
[image: Version 22.2]

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Not the first question I see, it looks like `r22.2` has some issues styling bars. Is this happening with `r22.1` ?

Comment: Also, what if you use `android:theme` rather than `app:theme`?

Comment: @mvai I don't know, I don't test code with `r22.1`.

Comment: @mvai It didn't help

Comment: I would go back to 22.1 and wait for a fix. But we won't know if 22.1 is OK until you test it :)

Comment: @mvai I test my code with 22.1 and I see wrong background in any mode :(

Comment: All I can say is that [from v22 on](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) (so v22.1 included) you should use `android:theme` rather than `app:theme`. Maybe v22.1 with `android:theme` will work. As for v22.2, I think there is a bug somewhere.

Comment: @mvai No, I'm using `android:theme` but background is white.